# Triple integral /polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let W be bounded by
$y=5-4x^2-4z^2$ and $y=x^2+z^2$

I have set them equal, and I obtain

$x^2 + z^2 = 1$

So I would be having

$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \int_{x^2+z^2}^{5-4x^2-4z^2} \rho(x,y,z)$ $dydxdz $

The shadow part would be

$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}  dxdz$

now I need to use polar coordinates, for the (x,z) plane. but how could I proceed?
would $x=\text{rcos} \psi$ , $z=\text{rsin} \psi$? what would the limits for $r, \psi$ and $y$ be and what would the integrand be, only $r$ when calculating the volume of $W$?

Comment: If you set $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $z=r\sin(\theta)$ your integral becomes $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int _0^1 \int_{r^2}^{5-4r^2}r\rho(r\cos(\theta),y,r\sin(\theta))dydrd\theta$$ Yes, if you're only interested in calculating the volume of $W$ your integrand would only contain an $r$.

Comment: @MatthewHolder: Thank you so much!